# REST call always return undefined (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm still new to Node.JS and I'm trying to call a REST API using GET method.
I use 'request' package from this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). The call actually works but when I try to return the response body from other .JS file, I get 'undefined'.

Here is my 'first.js'

```
var request = require('request');
var first = function (){
};
first.prototype.getValue = function (value){
    var thpath = somePath + value;
    var postheaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    var options = {
        url : 'https://' + thpath,
        method : 'GET',
        headers : postheaders,
    };
    var data_rec = "";
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            data_rec = JSON.parse(body);
            console.info(data_rec);
            return data_rec;
        } else return "failed to get";
    });
};
module.exports = first;
```

Here is my 'second.js'

```
var first = require('./first');
var instance = new first();
var val1 = instance.getValue(someValue);
console.info(val1);
```

The 'console.info(data_rec)' from 'first.js' returns a JSON (which means that the call is working). However, 'console.info(val1)' from 'second.js' returns 'undefined'. Can anybody find the solution?

Update:
I am able to get the solution by using [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request) package.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val1 = instance.getValue(someValue);
console.info(val1);
```

`instance.getValue` is an asynchronous method. Meaning javascript vm wont wait for response, it just goes on with next line ie `console.info(val1);` Ajax request takes time and response comes in only after some time, and triggers the success function.Till then val1 is undefined

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        data_rec = JSON.parse(body);
        console.info(data_rec);
        return data_rec;
    } else return "failed to get";
});
```

See that `console.info(data_rec);` is given inside the success function, success function is something that get called after response is successfully retrieved

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return asynchronous response in a synchronous manner which is not possible.
When you make the call, `first()` is executed and returned with no value and then async call completes. So `console.log` prints correctly, but you won't receive the value.

Modify this part of code

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            data_rec = JSON.parse(body);
            console.info(data_rec);
            return data_rec;
        } else return "failed to get";
    });
```

to this

```
var request = request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            data_rec = JSON.parse(body);
            console.info(data_rec);
        }
    });
return request.then(function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode >= 300) {
      return "failed to get";
    } else {
      return res.body.toString()
    }
  })
```

Comment: I can't find any 'request.then' method.